# Call an DOM HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<h1 class="entry-title">
    <a rel="bookmark" href="http://192.168.100.103/wp-final/?p=59">Featured Image Format</a>
</h1>
```

Hi, i want to add some css after `entry-title` class with jQuery, so I call it. If I use `$("h1.entry-title").text()`. The DOM value is only `Featured Image Format`. I also want to `<a href="...">` to be included. What syntax should I use?

--- edit ---

```
$.fn.fontcolor = function( options ) {
    var t = $("h1.entry-title").text();
    var splitT = t.split(" ");
    var halfIndex = Math.round(splitT.length / 3);
    var newText = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < splitT.length; i++) {
        if (i == halfIndex) {
            newText += "<span style='color:#337ab7'>";
        }
        newText += splitT[i] + " ";
    }
    newText += "</span>";

    return this.each(function(){
        el = $(this);
        el.html(newText);
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to add some styling, use `$("h1.entry-title").css('prop', 'value')`. Why do you need to use `text()`?

Comment: I think you need `$("h1.entry-title").html()`

Comment: @rory I will use it for Math.Round(), so I need called it all.

Comment: If you're calling math.round, why would you need all the HTML? Can you explain exactly what it is you're trying to do as at the moment the goal of the question isn't clear at all.

Comment: @satpal still not working.

Comment: @rory. I want to create plugin for change color title. Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks rory

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.html()` instead of `.text()`:

```
$("h1.entry-title").html()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("h1.entry-title *").css('prop', 'value');
```

apply css to all elements within h1 except the h1 tag

```
$("h1.entry-title").css('prop', 'value');
```

apply css for h1 tag